# How could I print to console in Share Extensions

Tags: swift, ios-app-extension

I am trying to use print in my Share Extension, I tried several method: `print, NSLog, os_log, Logger.log` but none of them work.

I have successfully attached to the process in Xcode and the breakpoints in this file work, but couldn't see any print output in the console. I am using Simulator of iOS 16.2 and Xcode 14.2 if that matters.

```
class ShareViewController: SLComposeServiceViewController {
    
    let log = Logger(subsystem: "com.example.app", category: "main");
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        print("viewDidAppear")
        NSLog("viewDidAppear")
        os_log("viewDidAppear")
        log.log("viewDidAppear")
        
    }
    
    
    override func didSelectPost() {

        print("didSelectPost")
        NSLog("didSelectPost")
        os_log("didSelectPost")
        log.log("didSelectPost")

    }
}
```

Comment: you can try debugPrint("didSelectPost")